# Running 'dpd keygen' throws an 'ENOENT' error on heroku

Tags: heroku, key, command-line-interface, dashboard, deployd

I installed deployd on Heroku.
When trying to access the dashboard, I get the following message:

> Use dpd showkey to get your app's key.

But running:

`heroku run dpd keygen`

gives the following error:

> { [Error: ENOENT, open '.dpd/keys.json'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT',
>   path: '.dpd/keys.json' }

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a ".dpd" folder in my heroku root folder.
To be able to commit, you also have to add the following file: ".add/.gitemptydir"

Then you have to create the key locally

```
dpd keygen
```

Then, do

```
git add *
git commit -am "added .dpd folder and key.json"
git push heroku master
```

You are then able to run

```
heroku run dpd showkey
```