# Deploying Deployd to Heroku Dashboard Key

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile, deployd

I have an [Deployd](http://deployd.com) application I am trying to deploy to Heroku. I have successfully been able to deploy the application and am able to hit it via it's url. I am now trying to access the dashboard. In order to access the [dashboard](http://docs.deployd.com/docs/server/your-server.html#s-Dashboard%20Access-2728), it requires I have the key generated from the server. I understand that there are two ways to do this.

The first method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121291/running-dpd-keygen-throws-an-enoent-error-on-heroku) generates the key locally and pushes it to heroku. I feel that this method is unsecure in the sense that the keys are published to a VCS.

The second [method](https://twitter.com/joe_wegner/status/294883668567142401) is the use the Procfile and list `dpd keygen` and `dpd showkey`. However for some reason this method does not work for me. I see the commands get executed in the heroku logs but it doesn't print out the keys and I cannot see it by executing `heroku run dpd showkey`.

I would like to figure out why listing the commands in my procfile does not work. Please find my file listed out below:

```
web: node app.js
cmd: dpd keygen
cmd: dpd showkey
```

My log file is as follows:

```
2015-08-30T19:18:25.012474+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `dpd showkey` by [email]
2015-08-30T19:18:28.196008+00:00 heroku[run.5122]: Starting process with command `dpd showkey`
2015-08-30T19:18:28.168161+00:00 heroku[run.5122]: Awaiting client
2015-08-30T19:18:28.501367+00:00 heroku[run.5122]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-30T19:18:31.023033+00:00 heroku[run.5122]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-30T19:18:31.012416+00:00 heroku[run.5122]: Process exited with status 0
2015-08-30T19:19:36.935285+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `dpd keygen` by [email]
2015-08-30T19:19:39.794903+00:00 heroku[run.3022]: Starting process with command `dpd keygen`
2015-08-30T19:19:39.768225+00:00 heroku[run.3022]: Awaiting client
2015-08-30T19:19:40.128378+00:00 heroku[run.3022]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-30T19:19:42.827722+00:00 heroku[run.3022]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-30T19:19:42.813695+00:00 heroku[run.3022]: Process exited with status 0
2015-08-30T19:19:51.655953+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `dpd showkey` by [email]
2015-08-30T19:19:54.911082+00:00 heroku[run.9997]: Awaiting client
2015-08-30T19:19:54.946930+00:00 heroku[run.9997]: Starting process with command `dpd showkey`
2015-08-30T19:19:55.293222+00:00 heroku[run.9997]: State changed from starting to up
2015-08-30T19:19:58.397128+00:00 heroku[run.9997]: State changed from up to complete
2015-08-30T19:19:58.384885+00:00 heroku[run.9997]: Process exited with status 0
2015-08-30T19:29:11.578546+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-08-30T19:29:11.578526+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-08-30T19:29:11.531233+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v22 created by [email]
2015-08-30T19:29:11.531111+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 27d1a9c by [email]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using npm's postinstall:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "dpd keygen && dpd showkey",
    "start": "node server"
},
```

The key then gets output in the log when pushing to the heroku repo, e.g.

> remote:        > dpd keygen && dpd showkey remote:         remote:
>   created key 1f89d0aa66b50fdd... remote:        Copy this key for use
>   in remote dashboard remote:         remote:
>   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

Comment: I am not working on this issue any more but I will mark this answer as the accepted answer based on the output. Thanks!